# Django Tastypie interaction with the API through PostMan to get parameter

Tags: python, django, postman

I want to test my function that get username and password in views from url using raw data below.
The problem is i dont know the correct way to create url for link to my function (login).

raw data :

```
{
    "type":"login",
    "username":"admin", 
    "password":"admin" 
}
```

content type : json

views.py:

```
def login(self, request, **kwargs):
        self.method_check(request, allowed=['post'])

        data = self.deserialize(request, request.raw_post_data, format=request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE', 'application/json'))

        username = data.get('username', '')
        password = data.get('password', '')
```